Syncfusion stacked graph renders badly efter building flutter web
Currently trying to create a stacked area graph with syncfusions stacked area graph.
While running it under localhost, I get this result
Graph under localhost
However, after pushing this to our stage environment I got these weird gaps
Graph in stage
Build command
flutter build web --release

The project is hosted with Firebase hosting.
My code for the StackedAreaGraph
StackedAreaSeries<T, dynamic>(
  dataSource: dataSource,
  xValueMapper: seriesData.xValueMapper,
  yValueMapper: seriesData.yValueMapper,enableTooltip: true,
  name: seriesData.seriesName,
  yAxisName: name,
  emptyPointSettings: const EmptyPointSettings(
  mode: EmptyPointMode.average
  ),
  color: color,
),

I have tried to both build with and without the -wasm tag when deploying, but neither made a difference.
Flutter version: 3.24.3
Dart SDK: 3.5.3
syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^27.1.50

Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are not open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.
